# Creating Complex JSON Object using JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, json

I am bit new to JSON world. And I have to use JavaScript to create following type of JSON structure. Not sure how to achieve this. Tried with following code, but unable to add second element("12101") as well as people to JSON Structure is where I am struggling.

```
var chat = {};
chat = {"101":{}};
chat["101"].people= {};
chat["101"].people = {"L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC":{}};
chat["101"].people.L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC = {"name":"vikram@qech.com"};
chat["101"].room= {};
```

**JSON structure to achieve**

```
{
  "101": {
    "people": {
      "L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC": {
        "name": "vikram@qtech.com",
        "inroom": "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1",
        "owns": "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1",
        "countrycode": "in",
        "device": "desktop",
        "roomname": "R1"
      },
      "qKCglYWI1hRhZUZCAAAD": {
        "name": "Ishim",
        "inroom": "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922",
        "owns": "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922",
        "roomname": "Ra"
      }
    },
    "room": {
      "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1": {
        "name": "R1",
        "id": "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1",
        "owner": "L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC",
        "people": [
          "L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC"
        ],
        "status": "available"
      },
      "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922": {
        "name": "Ra",
        "id": "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922",
        "owner": "qKCglYWI1hRhZUZCAAAD",
        "people": [
          "qKCglYWI1hRhZUZCAAAD"
        ],
        "status": "available"
      }
    }
  },
  "12101": {
    "people": {
      "K-Ar9GYKoAAAC": {
        "name": "Rahul.com",
        "inroom": "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1",
        "owns": "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1",
        "countrycode": "in",
        "device": "desktop",
        "roomname": "R1"
      },
      "I1hRhZUZCAAAD": {
        "name": "Vipul",
        "inroom": "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922",
        "owns": "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922",
        "roomname": "Ra"
      }
    },
    "room": {
      "b779-cfc396f0f8a1": {
        "name": "Rahul-R1",
        "id": "f787f316-6424-491b-b779-cfc396f0f8a1",
        "owner": "L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC",
        "people": [
          "L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC"
        ],
        "status": "available"
      },
      "b9b7-2f3fc0602922": {
        "name": "Vipul-Room1",
        "id": "2e52905d-951c-4990-b9b7-2f3fc0602922",
        "owner": "qKCglYWI1hRhZUZCAAAD",
        "people": [
          "qKCglYWI1hRhZUZCAAAD"
        ],
        "status": "available"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "-" is not a valid character for a key in JSON so: "L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC": {  won't work

Comment: If it helps, you can refer to an existing object (even in loops) via multiple variables. For instance, if you write `var chat = {"101": {} };` and then `var firstChat = chat["101"]`, you can make changes to `firstChat`, and when you take a look at `chat`, they will have applied there. Each array (`[]`) and object(`{}`) is an Object in the standard programming OOP sense.

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk: You can use any character as a [JSON](http://json.org/) property name. It only needs to be put in quotes and accessed with bracket notation. `{"L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC":true}` [is valid](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: @dakab: lets not confuse JSON with object literals. JSON requires every key to be in quotes. Object literals only required keys that at not valid identifier names to be quoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is invalid because the property name contains dashes.

```
chat["101"].people.L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC = {"name":"vikram@qech.com"};
```

To access it correctly, put it in quotes

```
chat["101"].people["L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC"] = {"name":"vikram@qech.com"};
```

Comment: "-" will still be invalid

Comment: No, dash is a valid javascript property

Comment: Sorry, that's correct, it's just me being confused ;P

Comment: Thanks . Able to achieve this based on input.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**bracket notation** as a property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) like this:

```
chat["12101"].people = {};
chat["101"].people["L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC"] = {"name":"vikram@qech.com"};
```

With it, it’s just a routine piece of work. It probably didn’t work right away since dot notation property access requires a [valid identifier name](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6). With bracket notation, you can use any string like `"L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAAAC"`.

Also note that in [JSON](http://json.org/), anything works as a property name too, as long as it is put in quotes. `{"L0b12leL-Ar9GYKoAC":true}` is [as valid](http://jsonlint.com/) as `{"":true}`.